# <script/> vs <script></script> with webpack and angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, webpack

After a two days fight with integrating angular with webpack I found a very strange behaviour.

In my html file I have been including the bundled JS source with

```
<script src="bundle.js"/>
```

This was not working at all. After I acidentally changed the line to

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

all of a sudden everything was fine.

With the `<script/>` style the html in the browser console was looking wired (tested with ie and chrome):

```
<body ng-app="app">
<h1>Angular + Webpack</h1>

<script src="bundle.js">

<p>{{1+1===2}}</p>

</body>   <-- why is this inserted
</html>   <-- why is this inserted
</script>  <-- where is this comming from
</body>
```

Only the `<h1>` title is visible in the browser, everything else is not shown.

My index.html looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Angular with Webpack</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
<h1>Angular + Webpack</h1>

<!-- strange behaviour with <script src="bundle.js"/> -->
<script src="bundle.js"></script>

<p>{{1+1===2}}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The index.js

```
import angular from 'angular';
var ngModule = angular.module('app', []);
```

And the webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    context: __dirname + '/app',
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/app',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    }

};
```

Is there an explanation why `<script/>` style is not working?

Comment: Self closing script tags were invalid XHTML constructs. This was way before HTML4. This restriction however exists even today in days of HTML5.

So the browser adds closing script tag and others to make it valid HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self-closing tags are allowed but ignored in HTML. That is, you can include a `/` character at the end of a tag, but it  has no meaning. Therefore

```
<script .../>
```

is exactly the same as

```
<script ...>
```

as far as HTML is concerned.